# transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug - Duplicate entry android/support/v4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I found this error in my project and not getting that where is it present?

Libraries:

[image: Image - Libraries]

Error:

[image: Image - Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords - Duplicate entry, with**Jar**Merging, and `android/support/v4`.

There seems to be a Jar file that exists maybe in the `libs/` directory that duplicates entries that are already being compiled.

You can delete any support library jar files from that folder